# Office 2013, 2016 QATs remove padding at right

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016, qat

Can anyone help with how to remove the blank padding at right of the QATs?

This is happening in both Word and Excel, 2013 and 2016.
[image: Word 2013 empty QAT padding- maximised]

[image: word 2013 QAT view completely empty, NOTHING shows when restored!]

Comment: Are there other items still needing to be displayed or is what is shown all the tools?

Comment: There is another row of buttons for each QAT which are not in the screenshots, I haven't checked if any are missing.  What I need are the ones which show in the main window as I use them all the time, particularly the first 9 which are activated by alt keys.

Comment: Does this happen without the Foxit Addin or other Addins? I have not seen this. Are your QAT modificatons stored in the default location or in another template?

Comment: Thanks Charles, it happens when Foxit and other add-ons are disabled.  The spacing is bigger on 2013 (local) than 2016 (MSO 365).  It is correct in 2010 with the same OfficeUI file.